# Save to Camera Roll using EXPO

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, native

I am trying to save an image to the camera-roll using Expo from a URL and my code is not working properly. Please take look and see if you can help me, as that would be really helpful and much appreciated.

This is the code:

```
const handleSave = async  (image) => {
  let cameraPermissions = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
  if (cameraPermissions !== 'granted'){
    cameraPermissions = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
  }
  if (cameraPermissions.status  === 'granted'){
    FileSystem.downloadAsync(
      image.largeImageURL,
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + image.id +'.jpg',
      console.log(image.largeImageURL)
    )
    .then(({uri})=>{
      MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(uri)
      alert('saved to photos')
    })

  } else {
    alert('It requires permissions to save photos')
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow MMNK, it would be helpful if you could specify what part of your code isn't working, are there any errors popping out, or something similar, as this would help pinpoint the problem for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleSave = async image  => {
      let cameraPrmissions = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL); 
      if(cameraPrmissions.status !== 'granted') {
        cameraPrmissions = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      }
      
      if(cameraPrmissions.status === 'granted') {        
        MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(image)
        alert('Image saved to Library')
      } else {
        console.log('You did not allow permissions to camera');
      }
}
```

Comment: While this code block answers the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: I fixed the ussue using abive code